# How do we compare the cost of running MongoDB in GCE vs using Google Cloud Datastore?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I knew [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) and [Google Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/) offer NoSQL database systems. 
I'm new to deploying a database. These are some of my confusions:

1. How do we compare the **cost of running MongoDB in Google Compute Engine** vs. **using Google Cloud Datastore**? Can you quote a small example estimate? We may find many related articles. But I couldn't find one that address this specific question.
2. I came to know about the [Click to Deploy](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher) option in Compute Engine. What is the difference(in cost/performance) between **manually configuring the Compute Engine for MongoDB** and **Click to Deploy option**?
3. Within the Click to Deploy option you'll find two options([this](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/click-to-deploy-images/mongodb?cat=DATABASE) and [this](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/bitnami-launchpad/mongodb?cat=DATABASE)) we can choose for MongoDB. Can you spot the difference between them? There is also a significant price difference between them.
4. Is it worthy to start developing in Google Cloud Datastore leaving my MongoDB skills?

I would prefer to know the answers on the basis of cost, development overhead and perfomance.

Comment: Datastore should be way cheaper, but that’s pure feeling. Click to deploy should be only a predefined ‘build’ of Mongo along with Compute engine machines configuration. The costs you see really depend on the VMs, and I think you can change the machine type AFTER deploying. Even if you choose Mongo, I would go with manual configuration. These are skills that you *need* to have anyway, IMO it makes no sense to help you with the first deploy and then leave you alone.

Comment: As far as I know, the Google Cloud platform will manage your backend instances for you if you use the datastore. This means less management on your end of starting up vm instances. If you choose to go the MongoDB route, it looks like the difference in price depends on the type of virtual machine you want to use. Another advantage of the datastore is that it works seamlessly with your other cloud microservices and projects.